# Override class field's ToString() method

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class

I'm wondering, is there any way to override `ToString()` method of the class field with type `byte[]`? I'm even not sure it's possible... Here is the sample code:

```
public class Object
{
    private byte[] _content;

    public byte[] Content
    {
        get
        {
            return _content;
        }

        internal set
        {
            _content = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to override the way how `Object.Content.ToString()` method is called?

**EDIT**: Why do I need it? I suppose that `Content` might be pure binary data, however it can be pure string too. I panned to use `Encoding.UT8.GetString(Object.Content)` in case if I will need text representation, but hey! what about `ToString()` it fits my goals perfectly, maybe I can use it somehow?

The obvious method is popping out my head — create a wrapper around `byte[]` and override its `ToString()` but this looks ugly for me and I don't think it worth it.

Is there any elegant way to solve this issue? Or work around it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no other way. But really, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe it's possible via an extension method? E.g. `public static ToString(this byte[]) { ... }` - but if it works I'm not sure about how it will box the value anyway ...

Comment: If you want the Object itself to be represented by the content, you could override the Object.ToString() instead.  Unless you want to use both or if you have more than one kind of content in the object.

Comment: Wouldn´t that cause problems with other byte[] objects? Perhaps you could extend you "Object" class with a method or property that returns the ToString() functionality you are looking for?

Comment: You can't no, but you can override ToString() in your class so that the output is the the desired string representation of your byte array and you would do Object.ToString().  I'm sure its just a silly example but please don't create a class called Object.

Comment: @vanhelgen, note that the extension method cannot be the same name as a member method of the object. Overload resolution will always pick the member method over the extension method as a better match.

Comment: btw, never call something `Object` ;p

Comment: It's just for demo purpose! Cross my heart!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot override or replace the implementation of `ToString()` on the byte array generally or the `Content` property specifically. To get your desired outcome, you could need to wrap the array, which you've stated you do not want to do.

You could also provide *another* property inside the class to effectively shadow the `Content` property, such as

```
public string ContentAsString
{
    get 
    {
        return /* custom string output of this.Content here */
    }
}
```

One other option is to *extend* the byte array (via an extension method) to provide a custom implementation of a string conversion (and by a different name) (same idea as above, expressed differently)

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this byte[] array)
    {
        return ...
    }
}

string result = obj.Content.ToCustomString();
```

Comment: I like an idea of using extensions. Will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context! If the context here is "to dipslay something meaningful in a PropertyGrid or DataGridView", then you can probably use a TypeConverter:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form {Controls = {
            new PropertyGrid {SelectedObject = new SomeType
            {
                Content = new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5}                                               
            }, Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
        }});
    }

    public class SomeType
    {
        private byte[] _content;
        [TypeConverter(typeof(HexConverter))]
        public byte[] Content
        {
            get
            {
                return _content;
            }

            internal set
            {
                _content = value;
            }
        }
    }
    class HexConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if(destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (value == null) return "";
                byte[] raw = (byte[]) value;
                var sb = new StringBuilder(2*raw.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++) sb.Append(raw[i].ToString("x2"));
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielHigarth has pointed out, there's no real nice way to do this and I'm not sure why you'd want to...

But, you could:

Use a tool such as postsharp to intercept all calls to `byte[].ToString()` from your assembly and return whatever you like instead of the actual result.

Use an extension method eg,

```
public static string ToElegantString(this byte[] bytes) {
{
  return "ElegantString";
}
```

Comment: What disadvantages this way have? I'm asking because this is pretty close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of overriding the .ToString() method, just modify the get function?

for example:

```
public string Content
{
    get
    {
        return YourByteFormatter(_content);
    }       
}
```

Comment: I need to switch between `byte[]` and `string` representations on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Define your Byte array as a separate Class, so you can give it a ToString() override.